# Xamarin IOS TableView do not updated in a While loop

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

If I want do add a item into the TableView then the loop must be stopped. But I have a WebResponse and by every HTTP Chunked the TableView need a new item.

Did anyone have a solution to add a item into a TableView without to stop the while loop?

this is my Thread

```
    new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            HttpRequest t = new HttpRequest(TableView, source);
            t.Start();
        });
    })).Start();
```

And this is my loop:

```
WebResponse webResponse = web.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

        var reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
        string telegram = "";
        int check = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

and in a funtion in the loop I do this

```
        (tableView.Source as TelegrammSource).AddTelegramm(details);
        tableView.ReloadData();
```

Comment: what do you mean by loop must be stopped, can you explain more.

Comment: Please show us your code.  Most likely if your loop is running on a background thread and you need to update your UI from the main thread.

Comment: I have editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

There a sample to finish async data requesting and refresh your tableview:

```
string strURL = "https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/";
    MyHTTPRequestManager.Instance.GetDataFromUrl (strURL,(string dataStr)=>{
        Console.WriteLine("Getting data succeed");
        Console.WriteLine("The dataStr = "+dataStr);
        //update your dataList here
        InvokeOnMainThread(delegate {
            //Update your tableView or collectionView here, all UI stuff must be invoke on Main thread
        });
    });
```

And this is the MyHTTPRequestManager.cs:

```
public class MyHTTPRequestManager
{
public delegate void GettingDataCallback(string dataStr);

private static MyHTTPRequestManager instance = null;
public static MyHTTPRequestManager Instance{
    get{
        if(null == instance)
            instance = new MyHTTPRequestManager();
        return instance;
    }
}

public void GetDataFromUrl(string strURL,GettingDataCallback callback)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Begin request data.");
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest request;
    request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);
    System.Net.HttpWebResponse response;
    response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    System.IO.StreamReader myreader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    string responseText = myreader.ReadToEnd();
    myreader.Close();
    Console.WriteLine ("Getting succeed, invoke callback.");
    callback.Invoke (responseText);
}
}
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: thanks for your Answer. Yes thats can help but I do not use the ReadToEnd() function. I am working with HTTP Chunkes. That is the reason why the connection will be open every time.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow when I at home and give you feedback

Comment: It should work, at least in my side, could you just post more detail to describe your problem about how didn't it work? Then maybe I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is my ViewDidLoad on the TableviewController

```
base.ViewDidLoad();
        Console.Out.WriteLine("ViewDidLoad");
        TableView.SeparatorColor = UIColor.Black;
        TableView.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine;
        source = new TelegrammSource();
        TableView.Source = source;
        new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                HttpRequest t = new HttpRequest(TableView, source);
                t.Start();
            });
        })).Start();
```

And this is my HttpRequest

```
public class HttpRequest
{
    //private volatile bool _shouldStop;
    public string url = "";
    private HttpWebRequest web = null;
    readonly UITableView tableView;

    public HttpRequest(UITableView tableView, TelegrammSource source)
    {
        this.tableView = tableView;


        url = "http://www.example.com";
        web = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        web.Credentials = new NetworkCredential((kanalsettings[(NSString)GlobaleVariablen.KE_BENUTZERNAME] as NSString), (kanalsettings[(NSString)GlobaleVariablen.KE_PASSWORT] as NSString));
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        WebResponse webResponse = web.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

        var reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
        string telegram = "";
        int check = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                        Process(telegram);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Process(string result)
    {
        var details = new TelegrammDetails();
        var xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(result);
        XmlNodeList telegram = xml.SelectNodes("/");
        foreach (XmlNode item in telegram)
        {

        }
        (tableView.Source as TelegrammSource).AddTelegramm(details);
        tableView.ReloadData();

    }

}
```